# Why does my Rectangle's Fill not update when the GradientStops within the Brush change?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to make a gradient editor in WPF. To do this, I'm using a GradientStopCollection as a DataContext for an Rectangle (to display the gradient) and an ItemsControl (to display controls for editing the Stops).

```
  <Window x:Class="My.MainWindow"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          Height="350" Width="525">
     <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.DataContext>
           <GradientStopCollection>
              <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset=".25"/>
              <GradientStop Color="White" Offset=".75"/>
           </GradientStopCollection>
        </StackPanel.DataContext>
        <Rectangle Height="100">
           <Rectangle.Fill>
              <LinearGradientBrush GradientStops="{Binding}"/>
           </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <Slider Maximum="1" Value="{Binding Offset}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
     </StackPanel>
  </Window>
```

When run the app and move the lower slider, Snoop tells me that the rectangle.Fill.GradientStops[1].Offset has changed. However, the Rectangle's gradient appears to have not changed to reflect the GradientStop's new offset.

Aren't Bindings supposed to make the Rectangle update automatically? How can I get the Rectangle's fill to update without needing to create a new set of GradientStops every time a user touches a slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GradientBrushes` don't automatically re-render when parts of stops change. If the `GradientStops` property itself is changed the brush will update. Rather than trying to build and reuse a single brush by binding parts you may be better off using an `IMultiValueConverter` with a `MultiBinding` to build a complete brush from the two slider values to apply to the `Fill` property.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was trying to prevent proliferation of objects. I plan to have N sliders and also have a way to change the Colors, so I was really hoping to use `GradientStop` as the object in the `ItemsControl`. It's good to know the `GradientBrush` doesn't automatically re-render - is there a method I can call to force it to update instead?

Comment: You could clear and then set the property again on the same brush with the same collection instance which will update. That way requires some code to set up so is less straightforward to integrate with the XAML in some cases.

Comment: WPF seems to be "smart" about culling PropertyChanged events that don't change the base object, so it looks like doing the "null and back again trick" is the most straightforward thing I can find that doesn't involve duplicating the collection. A little sad, but I guess I'll just have to bite the bullet and let the ugly code in.